# Retrieve Records from mysql that are over 60 days but less than 90 days in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find records in Mysql that are more than 60 days old but less than 90 days old.
The more than 60 days works but I can't seem to only get the records that are no older than 89 days.

```
SELECT * FROM signings WHERE datediff(now(), signstart) > 60 < 90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM signings WHERE datediff(now(), signstart) > 60 and datediff(now(), signstart) < 90
```

Comment: so when you use datediff and more than one condition you have to do datediff for each condition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM signings WHERE signstart BETWEEN 
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 day) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```